# Cast Integer Column to TEXT in TSVector trigger/to_tsvector update

Tags: postgresql, tsvector

I'm currently trying to build a fulltext search for one of my applications.
I want the search to also yield results when searching for customer numbers (i.e. the id column of the customer table).
However, the TSVector only seems to accept string values, attempting to include the id columns results in the following error:

> column "id" is not of a character type

Because of this, I was trying to simply cast the id column to type TEXT before inserting it, but neither the cast() nor the ::TEXT options appear to be valid within the following commands that I'm using in my application:

```
CREATE TRIGGER np_vector_update BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON "customer" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE tsvector_update_trigger("CustomerSearchVector", 'pg_catalog.german', "id", "firstName", "lastName", "company", "birthName")

UPDATE "customer" SET "CustomerSearchVector" = to_tsvector('german', "id" || ' ' || "firstName" || ' ' || "lastName" || ' ' || "company" || ' ' || "birthName")
```

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your second statement works fine for me.  You said it doesn't but didn't give an error message for it, so I have no idea what you meant.  You could write a trigger around that.

Or use a generated column.  You will have to add a cast for the int field, as the implicit cast is not considered immutable.

```
alter table customer add "CustomerSearchVector" tsvector generated always as 
  (to_tsvector('german', "id"::text || ' ' || "firstName" || ' ' || "lastName" || ' ' || "company" || ' ' || "birthName")) stored;
```

Comment: The query you've posted results in the following error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 2:   (to_tsvector('german', "id"::text || ' ' || "firstName" ||...

Comment: What version are you using?